# <h:selectOneMenu> valuChangeListener acting weird

Tags: jsf-2

I have a `<h:selectOneMenu>` to select the values from. and a `<p:commandButton>` to fire an action.
The `<p:commandButton>` works fine and does all I wish to work. but If I modify the code for `<h:selectOneMenu>` like the following, it stopped firing the action.

```
<h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{searchBean.handleValueChange}" value="#{searchBean.teamName}" immediate="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.teamName}"/>
    <f:ajax event="click"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The `valuChangeListener` even does not work when I select the value from the drop down.
ManagedBean is in `@ViewScoped` and above codes are in `<h:form>` tag.
What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: place `onchange="submit()"` in your `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag

Comment: why did you tag it to primefaces?

Comment: Have you applied any validation? Also try by removing `immediate="true"` from this tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to attach a `onchange="submit()"` JavaScript to the input component; Otherwise, no event will be fired.

```
        <h:selectOneMenu 
    valueChangeListener="#{searchBean.handleValueChange}" 
value="#{searchBean.teamName}" onchange="submit()" immediate="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.teamName}"/>
            <f:ajax event="click"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: I want the <p:commandButton> to fire an action which invokes a method. is that possible to do that?

Comment: I knew about the `onchange="submit()"` thing, but it automatically submits the form without waiting for the button to work

Comment: Do you know what you are asking? Ofcorse `<h:commandButton>` is able to fire a method.What is the relation of this thing with this question?

Comment: Even if I add this `onchange="submit()"` thing, The `<p:commandButton>` does not fire the action.

Comment: Listen! `valueChangeListener` is something else and invocation of method on `<h:commandButton>` is something else. Are you sure that It is clear to you what are you doing?

Comment: method will be invoked when you will change the value form selectOneMenu NOT when click on button.